# How to ignore ssl certification when using org.apache.commons.httpclient?

Tags: ssl, apache-commons-httpclient

when i use Apache package commons-httpclient-3.1.jar, i try to use the below logic to avoid ssl certification.

```
TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {new X509TrustManager() {
                public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null;
                }
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                }
                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                }
            }
        };

        // Install the all-trusting trust manager
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());

        // Create all-trusting host name verifier
        HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new HostnameVerifier() {
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                return true;
            }
        };

        // Install the all-trusting host verifier
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid);
```

but unfortunately, i still got errors:
the Https Client certificate authentication error :"javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException"

then i choose httpclient-4.3.3.jar, the above logic did not work as well, but if the below logic is added, it works.

```
  httpClient.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry().register(new Scheme("https", socketFactory, 443));
```

httpClient is the instance of DefaultHttpClient, socketfactory is initialized by:

```
   SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
   ctx.init(null, new TrustManager[] { xtm }, null);
   SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLSocketFactory(ctx);
   socketFactory.setHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);
```

It seems that Scheme Register is MUST.

but for package commons-httpclient-3.1.jar, how to do the scheme register?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

after investigation, the following way can meet the requirement.

```
Protocol easyhttps = new Protocol("https", (ProtocolSocketFactory)new EasySSLProtocolSocketFactory(), 443);
Protocol.registerProtocol("https", easyhttps);
```

EasySSLProtocolSocketFactory is in package commons-httpclient-contrib-3.1.jar